# Any counter example for this claim?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, divisor-sum

I would like to proof or  disproof this claim ,but i don't have enough information about divisor function structure .

**Claim** : for any positive integer $x, y ,n $  such that :$x\neq y$ and $n>1$,then   we have :
$$\sigma_y(n) \bmod \sigma_x(n)\neq 0 $$ if $$y\bmod x \neq 0$$
 "which it does  means no integer $n >1$ satisfies the titled claim"

**Edit01**: I edited the question as my first wrong typo and i meant in the case of  y mod $x \neq 0$   .

I run some computation in WA about that from $n=2  $ to $1000$ with $y =17$ and $x=15$ I have got  [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table+of+[sigma_17%28n%29mod+sigma_15%28n%29]%3D0%2Cn%3D2+to+1000%2C) and it's works with many values of $y \bmod x \neq 0$ , i would like to know if there some one give me any counter example or any idea for proving it correct

**Note**:$\sigma_y(n) , \sigma_x(n) =\sum d^y,\sum d^x,$ respectively are sum power divisor function

Thank you for any help

Comment: Related [question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/229068/for-which-x-and-y-does-sigma-xn-divide-sigma-yn-for-all-n?lq=1) about divisibility among power-divisor functions.

Comment: yes, it is my question there , and do you meant there is a counter example ?

Comment: No, I have no counterexample right now (it should be true).

Comment: just to look if my conjecture is true and to know more about divisibility among divisor function

Answer (score 0):

A possible counterexample is $y=1$, $x=2$ and $n=6$. Then $$2\bmod 1=0,$$ but $$\sigma_2(6) \bmod \sigma_1(6)=1^2+2^2+3^2+6^2\bmod 12\neq 0.$$
So we have $\sigma_y(n)\bmod \sigma_x(n)\neq 0$, although $y\bmod x=0$, i.e., although $y\bmod x\neq 0$ is *not* satisfied. Hence the "iff" is not true.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ,  but 0 mod 1 is 0 \neq 0 as i posted in the claim

Comment: and i think the necessary condition to get sigma_y(n) mod sigma_x(n)=0 is y mod x= 0

Comment: @ I posted in the claim iff y mod x diffrent from  0

Comment: Yes, but is it not true that $a\neq b$ iff $f(a)\neq f(b)$ is equivalent to $a=b$ iff $f(a)=f(b)$ ?

Comment: ah, ok, thanks , I meant in the case of y mod x \different from 0 no integer satisfied the titled property

Comment: ok, thanks for your help

Comment: @zeraouliarafik And "accepting" this answer is not an option because?